# Can I kill everyone in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

Basically, what I'm asking is if any NPCs are marked 'essential', meaning they can't be killed whatsoever (and attacking them will simply incapacitate them for a short time whereupon they will get up and pretend nothing has happened).

Is it possible for me to kill everyone in Fallout 4? Or are there any NPCs that have been marked essential and thus impossible for me to kill?

Comment: IIRC "unkillable NPCs" was added to combat a massive game breaker in oblivion and on. Before that, it was just accepted that you could break the game early on, and not be able to pass a certain midpoint. So I highly doubt all NPCs could be killable, even if due to the inclusion of a "yes man" NPC to combat this problem.

Comment: I'm quite surprised to see this with downvotes. Seems to be a totally reasonable question to me.

Comment: @shanodin My guess is it's being downvoted because the title is redundant with the tag. Should just be "Can I kill everyone?"

Comment: As far as I know in Fallout 2 and New Vegas anyone could be killed. In FO2 some kills (anyone in Arroyo) meant it's game over (with a special cutscene), while in FO:NV Yes Man just reincarnated as a new robot the next time you entered the area so you could still finish the game

Comment: @SztupY There are plenty of essential NPCs in New Vegas: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_characters

Comment: @ZacCrites: they are either companions (can be killed in hardcore mode) or children, none of them are essential because the story requires it

Comment: "Can I kill everyone in Fallout 4?" This is the Fallout series started. Question should be "Can I finish killing everyone in Fallout 4?"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**No**

If you attempt to kill some residents of Sanctuary, they will just fall to their knees and act disoriented. They will just get back up with their health fully regenerated after a minute or so.

Comment: Are there other settlements that have the same essential NPCs?

Comment: I guess Bethesda wasn't happy with how blood thirsty we were when they let us kill important NPC's in Oblivion.

Comment: @Memj *cough cough* that was Morrowind where literally everything was killable, not Oblivion.

Answer (score -2):

I killed everyone in Diamond City and they haven't respawned, only the kids are left.

However, killing everyone in the entire wasteland is a huge undertaking, which I've not accomplished.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question, it only means theres no one essential in Diamond City.